# MongoError: exception: invalid operator '$setUnion'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to use `$setUnion` in an aggregation query, it works just fine in the MongoDB console but when I try to do the same in my Node app with Mongoose, it fails with this error:

```
{ 
  [MongoError: exception: invalid operator '$setUnion']
  name: 'MongoError',
  errmsg: 'exception: invalid operator \'$setUnion\'',
  code: 15999,
  ok: 0 
}
```

Here is a simplified query that I tried and still failed in the app:

```
db.users.aggregate(
  { 
    $match: { _id: ObjectId("52c9375c497ed763f41941bd") }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      activities: { 
        $setUnion: [[1,2], [3,4]] 
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

MongoDB: 2.6.6, Mongoose: 3.8.21, Node: 0.10.26

Update: here is the Mongoose code

```
var User = require('./providers/db').User,
  mongoose = require('mongoose');

User.aggregate({ 
  $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId("52c9375c497ed763f41941bd") }
},
{
  $project: {
    activities: { 
      $setUnion: [[1,2], [3,4]] 
    }
  }
}, function (err, result) {
  if (err) { return console.log(err); }
  else { console.log(result); }
});
```

Comment: Well you could have posted the mongoose code that produces and error if that's what you thing is your question. But I think your mongoose code will be at fault with a "typo" when shown.

Comment: You're right my bad, I added the mongoose code to my question

Comment: Dude this works everywhere. You are doing something else wrong. I don't see any benefit here for anyone. Your `{ "$setUnion": [[1,2], [3,4]] }` example results in nothing positive over document inspection and just `[ 1, 4, 3 ,2 ]` as a result. You've made a coding error. Look for it and correct it. This works.

Comment: Of course the example doesn't result in anything, I simplified it to make sure there was no errors in it. All the code is in the question and I can't find any errors in it which is why I came here in the first place...

Comment: Well I think you made a clear syntax error somewhere or typing mistake. But since you force me to produce an example that proves your case is incorrect then I will.

Answer (score 0):

Really don't see the point here and did ask you to look at it. And cannot say I didn't warn you several times. I believe the term you are looking for is "thank you very much":

```js
var testSchema  = new Schema({},{ "strict": false });

var User = mongoose.model( "User", testSchema, "test" );

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/test");

async.series(
  [
    function(callback) {
      User.remove({},callback);
    },

    function(callback) {
      User.create({ "a": 1 },callback);
    },

    function(callback) {
      User.aggregate(
        [
          { "$project": {
            "activities": {
              "$setUnion": [[1,2],[3,4]]
            }
          }}
        ],
        function(err,result) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log( result );
          process.exit();
        }
      );
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  }
);
```

And returns :

```js
 [ { _id: 54b4c13decda256710226134, activities: [ 1, 4, 3, 2 ] } ]
```

just as would be expected.